# What does 전문 in this case?

Tags: vocabulary

눈에서 세인트 엘모의 불꽃이 튄다는 것, 그리고 [[전문이]] 있다는 것 정도가 그에 대한 정보의 전부였다.

+++++
Here's more context below.

그제서야 나는 스스로에게 질문을 던졌다. 도대체 여기서 뭘 하고 있는 거야. 다시 벼락을 맞을 것도 아니면서, 어쩌자고 이런 무리에 끼여들어, 뇌전의 전하 현상 따위를 공부하고 있는 것인가.

아무려나. 그게 J와의 첫 대면이었다. 눈에서 세인트 엘모의 불꽃이 튄다는 것, ****************그리고 전문이 있다는 것 정도가 그에 대한 정보의 전부였다. 진짜 만남은 그뒤에 이어졌다. 세 번의 연구 모임을 마쳤고 이미 '전격 세례' 경험이 있었으므로 나는 그날 모임 이후 바로 정회원으로 승격되었다. 게스 시계는 증거로 제출되었다. 정회원들은 그 시계를 소중히 다루었다. 손에서 손으로 넘겨받으며 성자의 유물이라도 되는 것처럼 경의를 표하며 살펴보았다. 모두들 하나씩은 세례를 증거할 만한 물품들이 있었다. 어떤 이는 우그러진 동전, 변색된 안경테를 내보여주었다.

Comment: Which novel is it from? If it's a Japanese novel, it could be some combination of any two Chinese letters with the (Korean) sound 전/문, either explained somewhere before in the novel or left "untranslated" by a careless translator.

Comment: Korean novel kim young ha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched the original text for a word that is almost not used in Korea.

김영하 / 피뢰침
Young Ha Kim, Lightning rod, right?

in this case, 전문 = Lichtenberg pattern engraved on man
                    (A tattoo engraved with lightning)

번개(전-Lightning) 문신(문-tattoo) transformed into Hanja, Chinese characters.

http://livedoor.4.blogimg.jp/karapaia_zaeega/imgs/7/8/784adb5b.jpg

Comment: That makes complete sense. I just knew it was definitely not the "expert" "expertise" meaning from the context

Comment: Yes, in fact the word is used 80% (expert),
19.9% (whole text),
The remaining 0.1% (lightning tattoo) ...

Comment: Thanks For the percentages. Whole text didn't even come to mind to me due to the contextt